# Load page into webview swift 2 from java class

Tags: swift, xcode7

I am developing an App for the iPhone using `Xwebview` which enables me to download a page then interact with the javascript on the downloaded page. 
All works, but if the internet connection drops, a default local page is loaded, informing the user there is no internet connection. The page displays a retry button that, when pressed checks, the internet connection: if the connection is made the app tries to connect again to the external page and load the page into the webview. 
I cannot get this to work: the code downloads the page (I can see this in my session data) but I can't get that page to load back into the webview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
              login()
        }

    func login()
    {
        // *********** Get stored hashkey **************
        let hashcode = getHashcode()

        // ********** Check network connection *********
        let netConnection = Connection.isConnectedToNetwork()
        print("net connection: ", netConnection)

        if netConnection == true
        {
            if hashcode != "00000"
            {

                print("local key found", hashcode)
                // We dont have local key
                let webview = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
                //webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "about:blank")!))
                view.addSubview(webview)
                webview.loadPlugin(jsapi(), namespace: "jsapi")


                let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: serverLocation + onlineLoginApi)!
                let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

                let paramString = "/?username=username&password=password"
                request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) {
                    (
                    let location, let response, let error) in

                    guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
                        print("error")
                        return
                    }

                    let urlContents = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: location!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                    guard let _:NSString = urlContents else {
                        print("error")
                        return
                    }

                    print(urlContents)

                }

                task.resume()

                // you must tell webview to load response
                webview.loadRequest(request)

            }
            else{

                print("local key found", hashcode)
                // ********* Found local key go to site pass key over ************

                let webview = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
                view.addSubview(webview)
                webview.loadPlugin(jsapi(), namespace: "jsapi")

                let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:serverLocation + onlineLoginApi + "?hashcode=\(hashcode)")!)
                req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                req.HTTPBody = "/?hashcode=\(hashcode)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(req)
                { data, response, error in
                    if error != nil
                    {
                        //Your HTTP request failed.
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        //Your HTTP request succeeded
                        print(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                    }
                    }.resume()
                webview.loadRequest(req)

            }

        }
        else{

            // No connection to internet

            let webview = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
            view.addSubview(webview)
            webview.loadPlugin(jsapi(), namespace: "jsapi")

            let root = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL!
            let url = root.URLByAppendingPathComponent("/www/error-no-connection.html")
            webview.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessToURL: root)
            print("No internet connection")

            }
    }
class jsapi: NSObject {


        // Reconnect button on interface
        func retryConnection()
        {
            print("Reconnect clicked")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
            let netConnections = Connection.isConnectedToNetwork()

                if netConnections == true {
                let netalert = UIAlertView(title: "Internet on line", message: nil, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                netalert.show()

                let url = self.serverLocation + self.onlineLoginApi
                let hashcode = ViewController().getHashcode()

                if(hashcode != "00000") {
                    let url = url + "?hashcode=\(hashcode)"
                    print("url: ", url)
                }

                   ViewController().loadPagelive(url)

                }


            else{
                let netalert = UIAlertView(title: "Internet off line", message: nil, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                netalert.show()
                }
            }
            print("retryConnect end")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add more information? Which part, from button press to the request, is not working? What have you tried to fix and debug? Please consider adding some code, without it we can't help you.

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that this is my first post ever, I have added the code. as you can see the javascript is checking the connection then creating the url and trying to run up the app again. The user has a stored hash code to use if they have already registered with the site, After checking the internet connection i have tried to create another function ViewController().loadPagelive(url) to load the page but that does not work

Comment: No problem, but I suggest to read StackOverflow tutorial on how to write a question, otherwise future post will be probably closed. Looking the code, there are multiple things that can go wrong: when you press the retry button, which prints do you see in the console? Anyway, I see that you try to perform the loadPageLive on a new instance of ViewController, not on the current one: that's why you don't see any update

Comment: Ok great, sorry about the posting mistakes i will have a read for future. So just going forward with my code How would i call the current/correct view controller? the only reason I called ViewController().loadPagelive(url) is because i thought i had to call out of the java class jsapi to get back to the viewcontroller

Comment: I've added an answer: you can't copy/paste because you need multiple changes on your code, but it should be easy to implement. Feel free to ask in case you find any problem.

Comment: If you're really using Swift2 I would *highly* recommend updating. it's now 2+years out of date and unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to perform the `loadPagelive(url)` on a new instance of your `ViewController`, not on the current one shown on the screen, that's why you don't see any update.

You should create a delegate or a completion block in order to execute code on you ViewController instance loaded on the screen: every time you do `ViewController()`, a new object is created.

You can try using the delegate pattern, which is simple to achieve. I will try to focus on the important part and create something that can be used with your existing code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let jsapi = jsapi() // You can use only 1 instance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set your ViewController as a delegate, so the jsapi can update it
        jsapi.viewController = self
        login()
    }

    func loadPagelive(_ url: URL) {
        // Load page, probably you already have it
    }
}

class jsapi: NSObject {
    weak var viewController: ViewController?

    func retryConnection() {
       // We check if the delegate is set, otherwise it won't work
       guard viewController = viewController else {
           print("Error: delegate not available")
       }

       [... your code ...]

       // We call the original (and hopefully unique) instance of ViewController
       viewController.loadPagelive(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marco, sorry if you saw my last post, the code you gave me worked, i just had to change it a bit. 'self.viewController!.loadPagelive(url)'